# Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the IntersectsWith function, or the Rectangles class/constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm trying to write some code for a challenge calculating the total area of an array of rectangles, and subtracting the area of their overlaps. I was thinking of using System.Drawing.Rectangles and a custom `IEqualityComparer` to use `GroupBy` to group them into rectangles that intersect with each other, but I've hit a snag with something more basic, in that the `IntersectsWith` method is only returning true when the rectangles are identical, and Intersect is giving what seem to be inaccurate results:

```
var a = new Rectangle(0,1,1,1); //1x1 square with top left at (0,1)
var b = new Rectangle(0,2,2,2); //2x2 square with top left at (0,2)
var c = Rectangle.Intersect(a,b);// should have an intersect = the first rectangle **if I understand it correctly**
Console.WriteLine(c); //=> {X=0,Y=2,Width=1,Height=0}
```

Is there any way to check if this is being overridden somewhere in the test suite? Or am I just approaching this in an ignorant way?

Comment: Your code does not compile because there is no `b`. Please post a [mre], i.e. code that you have actually run

Comment: sorry, simple, typo, second line was meant to be 'var b ...'

Comment: _should have an intersect_ . No! - The interection is correct: The 2nd rectangle starts at y=2 and the 1st one ends at y=1. Hence: No intersection

Comment: No, not a simply typo, because you forgot all the semicolons, too. I really mean it, provide [mre]s here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Intersection is correct:

[image]

The first rectangle (red) and the second rectangle (green) do have exactly this 0-height rectangle, that is marked yellow in common.

if you want to know if there is a non-empty intersection, then you should intersect and check the area to be > 0.

Comment: Wait, so the units for the position are different from the units for the height/width? Because the green rectangle is positioned at (0,4) in your drawing, and the red one at (0,2), when they should be (0,2) and (0,1) respectively. according to the documentation on the rectangle constructor, the position is of the top left of the rectangle. And add to that, when I use just the coordinates and height/width, instead of the function : ((b.X + b.Width) >= a.X && b.X <= a.X + a.Width) && (b.Y >= (a.Y - a.Height) && (b.Y - b.Height) <= a.Y), I get that they intersect

Comment: @gofal3, the `Y` axis on the picture is incorrect, in `GDI+` by default `Y` axis points down, as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-types-of-coordinate-systems-about)  (and `System.Drawing` is based on `GDI+` as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-5.0#remarks) )

Comment: Reviewing the documentation, and the behavior of the intersect function, it looks like the System.Drawing.Rectangle Constructor is on the top left, but because of the way the axis is oriented, I was projecting it into the wrong region of the cartesian plane.

Comment: @Renat: agree. I am so much more used to mathematics. But the error is just a mirroring, which is invariant to this problem. But thanks for pointing to it.